# error "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rust, rust-cargo, actix-web

Here is My Docker File:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev

RUN apt-get install -y -q build-essential curl
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /command-agent
COPY . /command-agent
RUN cargo build --release
COPY /command-agent/target/release/command-agent /
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT command-agent
```

**Its build successfully docker image but when i run that container its gives error:**

*command-agent: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /command-agent/command-agent)*

I do not understand, How can i fix this issue ?

Comment: Means exactly what it says -- you're not running against the same libc that compilation was against. Be sure you compile executables on the same platform you're going to run them on unless you're going to make sure they're static.

Comment: no sir, when i run the binary in my ubuntu machine...its working fine....in my application i use kafka and actix-web.....but docker container giving this error

Comment: Right, but which _version_ of Ubuntu is your container running, vs which version is your working host running? Specifically, you need to compare the libc releases between them.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 21.10
Release: 21.10
Codename: impish

Comment: Ask your package manager (I haven't used Ubuntu in long enough I don't remember dpkg commands) which package provides your `libc.so.6`, _including_ the exact version number, on both machines.

Comment: You can also use `objdump` or `nm` to look at the specific symbols exported by each library.

Comment: thanks sir...i inform you after applying your instruction

Comment: BTW, is there any chance that what you're `COPY`ing in already has precompiled executables (or shared objects from a partial compilation) inside it, so the `RUN cargo build --release` is leaving them alone instead of replacing them? I haven't seen this error in the Rust world with any frequency, but it's the kind of thing I saw _all the time_ doing porting/packaging work in C, when someone bundled up a "source tarball" that hadn't been `make clean`ed first.

Comment: i also make file by copying binary file...but thats giving me same error

Comment: @CharlesDuffy has a good point. Unless you have a `.dockerignore` file set up correctly, the `target` directory will also be copied, and then the `cargo build` command will not actually rebuild if you have already run the build locally.

Comment: Ok, let me set up a .dockerignore file

Comment: To be clear / explicit, you want to be sure the `target/` directory is ignored during the COPY.

Comment: sure sir, i inform you after applying

Comment: @Charles Duffy sir....thanks a lot sir, its working now for me to avoid target dir ... after then modify some entry point. your instruction giving me some important concept. 
please take my respect to you sir

Comment: @Herohtar sir, thanks a lot for your quick response and help me understand possible problem scope. please take my respect to you. thanks again sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ITs works for me when i avoid `/target` directory and now working both version of `ubuntu 20.04` and `21.10`. Giving thanks to **@Charles Duffy** and **@Herohtar** for their important and useful instruction,

```
FROM ubuntu:21.10
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
RUN apt-get install libssl-dev

RUN apt-get install -y -q build-essential curl
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- -y
ENV PATH="/root/.cargo/bin:${PATH}"

WORKDIR /command-agent
COPY ./src/. /command-agent/src/
COPY .env /command-agent/
COPY Cargo.toml /command-agent/
COPY Cargo.lock /command-agent/
RUN cargo build --release

EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT /command-agent/target/release/command-agent
```