# compiling against glibc 2.33 results in different optimization, glibc version dependency

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ld, glibc

I have a bit of C code that I'm cross-compiling with gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf on Ubuntu.

On Ubuntu Focal, compiled with `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0` and libc6-dev-armhf-cross 2.31

`objdump -p` tells me:

```
Version References:
  required from ld-linux-armhf.so.3:
    0x0d696914 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.4
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x0d696914 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.4
```

On Ubuntu Jammy compiled using `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0` and libc6-dev-armhf-cross 2.33

```
Version References:
  required from ld-linux-armhf.so.3:
    0x0d696914 0x00 04 GLIBC_2.4
  required from libc.so.6:
    0x069691b3 0x00 05 GLIBC_2.33
    0x069691b4 0x00 03 GLIBC_2.34
    0x0d696914 0x00 02 GLIBC_2.4
```

This causes the executable to not be runnable on distributions with older libc.

The offending symbols appear to be:

```
# objdump -T myapp |grep -w GLIBC_2.33
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000 (GLIBC_2.33) stat
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000 (GLIBC_2.33) fstat
```

While I do use these functions, they appear to be optimized out as `__xstat` when compiled on gcc 7 on the Ubuntu Focal host.  If I inspect the symbols with `nm`:

```
$ nm src/i2c_eeprom.o
...
00000064 r .LC6
         U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
         U __fprintf_chk
         U __fxstat
         U __snprintf_chk
         U __stack_chk_fail
         U __stack_chk_guard
         U __xstat
         U close
000001c5 T eeprom_exists
0000011d T eeprom_read
...
00000129 T eeprom_write
         U lseek
         U open
00000001 T open_eeprom
         U perror
         U read
         U stderr
         U write
```

But on Jammy/ GCC 11/ libc 2.33 I get:

```
$ nm src/i2c_eeprom.o
...
00000064 r .LC6
         U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
         U __fprintf_chk
         U __snprintf_chk
         U __stack_chk_fail
         U __stack_chk_guard
         U close
0000028d T eeprom_exists
00000201 T eeprom_read
...
00000145 T eeprom_write
         U fstat
         U lseek
         U open
00000001 T open_eeprom
         U perror
         U read
         U stat
         U stderr
         U write
```

So is it possible to make this code compile under Ubuntu Jammy/ gcc 11/ glibc 2.33 without linking those symbols that cause a hard requirement on glibc 2.33?

### Update

As suggested, I have tried the `__asm` hack however there is no 2.4 versioned `stat` or `fstat`:

```
# objdump -T /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6 | grep -w stat
000a25d9  w   DF .text  0000000e  GLIBC_2.33  stat

# objdump -T /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6 | grep -w fstat
000a25e9  w   DF .text  00000030  GLIBC_2.33  fstat
```

so I cannot do

```
__asm__(".symver fstat,fstat@GLIBC_2.4");
```

#### somewhat related references:

- [error "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71886453/error-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-version-glibc-2-33-not-found)
- [Moving to different Linux build system, getting error: undefined symbol: stat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44294173/moving-to-different-linux-build-system-getting-error-undefined-symbol-stat/44320282#44320282)

Comment: The post https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858996/1212012 may answer you question.
A simple `__asm__(".symver stat,stat@GLIBC_2.4");` well placed (and for `fstat` too) could solve it.

Comment: If you need compatibility with older GLIBC, you _must_ compile and link against older GLIBC. The `.symver` hack can cause all kinds of misbehavior, don't do it!

Comment: @Mathieu I wish I could, but `objdump -T /usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6 | grep -w fstat` shows only `GLIBC_2.33` for `stat` and `fstat`. :(   If I add the line you suggested I get a compilation error.